# dell studio 1558 multi touchpad multi finger

Tags: touchpad

Recently I bought an Intel Core i7 Dell laptop fully integrated. I have an ATi Radeon 1 GB ram graphic card and so on.

Everything works fine even the brightness, but when I try the multi touch multi finger(touchpad which enables two or more finger) the pointer jumps and go there and go here and so

It's very annoying because when I'm trying to write this question I cannot let the pointer be cool! when I accidentally the touchpad it is very annoying.

How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Linux, then I've found that it's difficult (impossible) to find a driver for the multi-touch touchpads that Dell puts into their new computers.

However, if you're using Windows, there is no reason that the pointer should jump around unless your touchpad is defective, in which case you should send it back to Dell for a replacement.

Comment: i'm talking about using dell on linux specifically in ubuntu lucid 10.04 also i discovered that the camera does not work also. Any response could help

In windows all of the hardware feature works fine. i dont have any problem using this laptop in windows.

Comment: @christian It's definitely a driver issue. I find that with new laptops, it's difficult to get some pieces of hardware (wireless card, ethernet, camera, touch pad, sound) working correctly in linux, because, while the linux and ubuntu community are amazing, they aren't fast enough to write drivers for the newest hardware. Basically, ubuntu may not work with your laptop until someone authors the proper drivers.